# Value is false but still giving error null check operator

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable

You understand better when see the code and error.

I have a StatelessWidget names StateWidget like this:

```
class StateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.readyWidget,
    this.error = false,
    this.errorWidget,
    this.loading = false,
    this.loadingWidget,
  });

  final Widget readyWidget;
  final bool error;
  final Widget? errorWidget;
  final bool loading;
  final Widget? loadingWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loading) {
      return loadingWidget ?? LoadingCircularProgressIndicatorWidget();
    }

    if (error) {
      return errorWidget ?? ErrorIconWidget();
    }

    if (!loading && !error) return readyWidget;

    return Container();
  }
}
```

And I have a StatefulWidget named StateWidgetExampleView like this:

```
class StateWidgetExampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateWidgetExampleView({super.key});

  @override
  State<StateWidgetExampleView> createState() => _StateWidgetExampleViewState();
}

class _StateWidgetExampleViewState extends State<StateWidgetExampleView> {
  bool loading = true;
  String? data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).then((value) {
      data = "Gelen Veri!";
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("StateWidgetExampleView"),
      ),
      body: StateWidget(
        loading: loading,
        error: data == null,
        readyWidget: Text(data!),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get a sample data in initState function in 1 seconds. You guess that "loadingWidget appears because of loading is true". This idea is kind of true but it throws error like `Null check operator used on a null value`. I think this renders the all widgets, then checks the conditions. Let's look at the error and wait 1 seconds then our StateWidget is ready. I want a structure that I can control error, loading and ready widgets. But it throws like this error. How can I build the structure that I want?

Error:
[image]

Data is loading:
[image]

Data is loaded:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it "readyWidget" to "readyBuilder". So, I did it a function returns widget. Now there is no error, it's like I want! ^^

StateWidgetExampleView:

```
class StateWidgetExampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateWidgetExampleView({super.key});

  @override
  State<StateWidgetExampleView> createState() => _StateWidgetExampleViewState();
}

class _StateWidgetExampleViewState extends State<StateWidgetExampleView> {
  bool loading = true;
  String? data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).then((value) {
      data = "Gelen Veri!";
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("StateWidgetExampleView"),
      ),
      body: StateWidget(
        loading: loading,
        error: data == null,
        readyBuilder: () => Text(data!),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

StateWidget:

```
class StateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.readyBuilder,
    this.error = false,
    this.errorWidget,
    this.loading = false,
    this.loadingWidget,
  });

  final Widget Function() readyBuilder;
  final bool error;
  final Widget? errorWidget;
  final bool loading;
  final Widget? loadingWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        if (loading) {
          return loadingWidget ?? LoadingCircularProgressIndicatorWidget();
        }

        if (error) {
          return errorWidget ?? ErrorIconWidget();
        }

        return readyBuilder();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StateWidget` widget is being creating from 1st frame. Even though you've waited some frame to handle null. But

This

```
body: StateWidget(
  loading: loading,
  error: data == null,
  readyWidget: Text(data!),/// here means create with current data
),
```

So the `Text` widget doesn't accept null and while using null-assert, it is throwing the error.

You've hidden the error on UI, not on compiler because `Text()` widget is creating from 1st frame.

You can provide default value like `readyWidget: Text(data??"")`.

Comment: Then the structure I imagine can't solve my problem, right? If I use this structure, I have to control all of errors like your code?

Comment: I am afraid it won't be possible with current thought, maybe you can check riverpod structure, it is providing the thing you are trying to get.

Comment: I solved my problem in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423317/9923274

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired functionality by using a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget.

```
class StateWidgetExampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateWidgetExampleView({super.key});

  @override
  State<StateWidgetExampleView> createState() => _StateWidgetExampleViewState();
}

class _StateWidgetExampleViewState extends State<StateWidgetExampleView> {
  late final Future<String> _data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _data = Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).then((value) {
      return "Gelen Veri!";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("StateWidgetExampleView"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _data,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the structure I want. I want a simple structure and control all of states.